# react-transition-group not work until reload the page

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router

I made an simple taskshceduler with react router 5 and react redux and work fine still.

Now I try animating between different route with react-transition-group.

If I click the url changed BUT the screen not re-render until i reload the page mannualy.

Th animation only works when i use the backward button on the browser

I not get error to the console.

What is the problem and What is the solution?

Thank you

App.js

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, Suspense } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Notification from "./shared/UIElements/Notification";
import { sendCartData, fetchCartData } from "./store/cart-actions";
import Auth from "./Auth/page/Auth";
import TaskMain from "./tasks/page/TaskMain";
import TaskFilter from "./tasks/page/TaskFilter";
import MainNavigation from "./Layout/Navigation/MainNavigation";
import LoadingSpinner from "./shared/UIElements/LoadingSpinner";
import TransitionGroup from "react-transition-group/TransitionGroup";
import CSSTransition from "react-transition-group/CSSTransition";
import "../src/scss/styles.css";

import UpdateTask from "./tasks/page/UpdateTask";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
import NewTask from "./tasks/page/NewTask";

let isInitial = true;



function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const notification = useSelector((state) => state.ui.notification);
  const logged = useSelector((state) => state.cart.logged);
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCartData());
    console.log(`fetch usefeect`);
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitial) {
      isInitial = false;
      return;
    }

    if (cart.changed) {
      dispatch(sendCartData(cart));
    }
  }, [cart, dispatch]);
 

  let routes;
  if (!logged) {
    routes = (
      <Switch location={location}>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Auth />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <Switch location={location}>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <TaskMain />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/tasks/new" exact>
          <NewTask />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/tasks/update/:id" exact>
          <UpdateTask />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/items" exact>
          <TaskFilter />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        {notification && (
          <Notification
            status={notification.status}
            title={notification.title}
            message={notification.message}
          />
        )}
        <MainNavigation />
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
          timeout={1250}
          classNames='fade'
          key={location.key}
          >
            <Suspense
              fallback={
                <div className="center">
                  <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
                </div>
              }
            >
              {routes}
            </Suspense>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1250ms ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

MainNavigation.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import NavLinks from './NavLinks';
import SideDrawer from './SideDrawer';
import Backdrop from '../UIElements/Backdrop';


const MainNavigation = (props) => {
  const [drawerIsOpen, setDrawerIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const openDrawerHandler = () => {
    setDrawerIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeDrawerHandler = () => {
    setDrawerIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      
      {drawerIsOpen && <Backdrop onClick={closeDrawerHandler} />}
      <SideDrawer show={drawerIsOpen} onClick={closeDrawerHandler}>
        <nav className="main-navigation__drawer-nav">
          <NavLinks />
        </nav>
      </SideDrawer>
      <header className="main-header header-grid">
    
        <button
          className="main-navigation__menu-btn"
          onClick={openDrawerHandler}
        >
          <span />
          <span />
          <span />
        </button>

        <div className="title-grid">
          <h1 className="main-navigation__title fontsize-18">TODO APP</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="links-grid">
          <NavLinks />
        </div>
     
      </header>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default MainNavigation;
```

NavLink.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { cartActions } from "../../store/cart-slice";


const NavLinks = (props) => {
  const logged = useSelector((state) => state.cart.logged);
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const foOldalHandler = () => {
    history.push(`/`);
  };
  const szuresHandler = () => {
    history.push(`/items`);
  };
  const logoutHanler = () => {
    dispatch(cartActions.logout());   
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <nav className="nav-links">
          <button className="nav-links-button" onClick={foOldalHandler}>Főoldal</button>
          {logged && <button  className="nav-links-button"  onClick={szuresHandler}>Szűrés</button>}
          {logged && <button  className="nav-links-button"  onClick={logoutHanler}>Kijelentkezés</button>}
        </nav>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default NavLinks;
```

SideDrawer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

const SideDrawer = props => {
  const content = (
    <CSSTransition
      in={props.show}
      timeout={200}
      classNames="slide-in-left"
      mountOnEnter
      unmountOnExit
    >
      <aside className="side-drawer" onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</aside>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(content, document.getElementById('drawer-hook'));
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './store/index';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
 
} from "react-router-dom";


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
   
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

NewTask.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { cartActions } from "../../store/cart-slice";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

export default function NewTask() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const username = useSelector((state) => state.cart.username);

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("aktiv");

  const history = useHistory();
  const usernameChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const descriptionChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setDescription(event.target.value);
  };

  const statusChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setStatus(event.target.value);
  };

  const newTaskHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`title: ${title} description ${description} status: ${status}`);
    dispatch(
      cartActions.addTask({
        id: uuid(),
        username,
        title,
        description,
        status,
      })
    );
    history.push("/");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='main-introduction'>
    
      <h2 >Hello {username}!</h2>
      <h1>Milyen feladatot szeretnél elvégezni?</h1>
      </div>
     
      <form onSubmit={newTaskHandler}>
        <label  htmlFor="title">A feladat címe</label>
        <br></br>
        <input
       
          id="title"
          type="text"
          value={title}
          onChange={usernameChangeHandler}
          className='input-width'
          required
        />
           <br></br>
        <label htmlFor="description">A feladat leírása:</label>
        <br></br>
        <input
        
          id="description"
          type="text"
          value={description}
          onChange={descriptionChangeHandler}
          className='input-width'
          required
        />
           <br></br>
        <label htmlFor="status">A feladat állapotta:</label>
        <br></br>
        <div onChange={statusChangeHandler}>
          <input type="radio" value="aktiv" name="status" required /> Aktív
          <input type="radio" value="kesz" name="status" /> Teljesített
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <button type="submit">Hozzáad</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-spring": "^9.4.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "use-sound": "^4.0.1",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

Comment: Can you include all relevant routing/navigation code, but specifically the `MainNavigation` were I am guessing you've housed your navigation links? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A moment I will added my main navigation also. I don't think that relevant in this situation

Comment: Can you add the `NavLinks` component, and any other components from here through to where you are actually rendering your links? The links are sort of relevant if clicking them is updating the URL in the address bar but somehow the router isn't aware of the change.

Comment: I added yet more component include NavLinks.js What component should added? Thank you for help

Comment: yes I notice the URL change but not alter the page until i reload the page

Comment: I dont fully underrstand this sentence .Can you add the NavLinks component, and any other components from here through to where you are actually rendering your links?-

Comment: Yeah, I was looking to verify you didn't have more than one router in your app, I wanted to see from `MainNavigation` all the way to where you were linking/pushing new routes. There aren't any that I see. What I suspect now that you've added a lot more of your root code is that `routes` is redeclared each render cycle, which might be remounting a good chunk of your app. Try memoizing the `routes` value. Think you could create a running codesandbox demo of your app (*sans the redux code*) that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242578/discussion-between-milan-nikolics-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

I think found the answer. with help for Drew Reese

Organize my route components different file.

It cause the right rendering.

Besides that using **location.pathname** instead location.key.

If you have better solution please write here

Thank you

App.js

```
import {
  Fragment,
  useEffect,
  Suspense,
} from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Notification from "./shared/UIElements/Notification";
import { sendCartData, fetchCartData } from "./store/cart-actions";
import MainNavigation from "./Layout/Navigation/MainNavigation";
import LoadingSpinner from "./shared/UIElements/LoadingSpinner";
import TransitionGroup from "react-transition-group/TransitionGroup";
import CSSTransition from "react-transition-group/CSSTransition";
import "../src/scss/styles.css";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  useLocation,

} from "react-router-dom";
import AuthenticationApp from "./AuthenticationApp";
import TaskApp from "./TaskApp";

let isInitial = true;

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const notification = useSelector((state) => state.ui.notification);
  const logged = useSelector((state) => state.cart.logged);
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCartData());
    console.log(`fetch usefeect`);
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitial) {
      isInitial = false;
      return;
    }

    if (cart.changed) {
      dispatch(sendCartData(cart));
    }
  }, [cart, dispatch]);
 
  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        {notification && (
          <Notification
            status={notification.status}
            title={notification.title}
            message={notification.message}
          />
        )}
        <MainNavigation />
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
            timeout={1250}
            classNames="fade"
            pathname={location.pathname}
          >
            <Suspense
              fallback={
                <div className="center">
                  <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
                </div>
              }
            >
              {!logged && <AuthenticationApp />}
              {logged && <TaskApp />}
            </Suspense>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AuthenticationApp.js

```
import { Route, Redirect, Switch, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import TransitionGroup from "react-transition-group/TransitionGroup";
import CSSTransition from "react-transition-group/CSSTransition";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import LoadingSpinner from "./shared/UIElements/LoadingSpinner";

import Auth from "./Auth/page/Auth";

const AuthenticationApp = ({}) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <TransitionGroup>
      <CSSTransition timeout={1250} classNames="fade" key={location.pathname}>
        <Suspense
          fallback={
            <div className="center">
              <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
            </div>
          }
        >
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact>
              <Auth />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/" />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
  );
};

export default AuthenticationApp;
```

TaskApp.js

```
import { Route, Redirect, Switch, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import TransitionGroup from "react-transition-group/TransitionGroup";
import CSSTransition from "react-transition-group/CSSTransition";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import LoadingSpinner from "./shared/UIElements/LoadingSpinner";
import TaskMain from "./tasks/page/TaskMain";
import NewTask from "./tasks/page/NewTask";
import UpdateTask from "./tasks/page/UpdateTask";
import TaskFilter from "./tasks/page/TaskFilter";

const TaskApp = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <TransitionGroup>
      <CSSTransition timeout={1250} classNames="fade" key={location.pathname}>
        <Suspense
          fallback={
            <div className="center">
              <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
            </div>
          }
        >
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact>
              <TaskMain />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/tasks/new" exact>
              <NewTask />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/tasks/update/:id" exact>
              <UpdateTask />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/items" exact>
              <TaskFilter />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/" />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
  );
};

export default TaskApp;
```